# How do I break Test Unit Code off into 'Re-usable' Code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, mocking, httpcontext

I am mocking the HTTPContext in some test methods.  I have a lot of methods I need to write so I would rather re-use code than write it each time.  Stay DRY.

I am implementing [this method of Faking (Mocking) HTTPContext](http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2013/04/30/mocking-httpcontext-with-fake-it-easy/).  I read that I need to break this off into a **Factory** to re-use it in other Unit-Test's.

**Question:** How do I put this code into a Factory to re-use it in Unit-Tests?  Is there a better way other that a 'Factory' to re-use this?  How can I implement that.

---

**Test Code**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public void Index()
    {
        Response.Write("This is fiddly");
        Response.Flush();
    }
}

//Unit Test

[Fact]

public void Should_contain_fiddly_in_response()
{

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var formCollection = new NameValueCollection();
    formCollection.Add("MyPostedData", "Boo");

    var request = A.Fake<HttpRequestBase>();
    A.CallTo(() => request.HttpMethod).Returns("POST");
    A.CallTo(() => request.Headers).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
    A.CallTo(() => request.Form).Returns(formCollection);
    A.CallTo(() => request.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());

    var response = A.Fake<HttpResponseBase>();
    A.CallTo(() => response.Write(A<string>.Ignored)).Invokes((string x) => sb.Append(x));

    var mockHttpContext = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
    A.CallTo(() => mockHttpContext.Request).Returns(request);
    A.CallTo(() => mockHttpContext.Response).Returns(response);

    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext, new RouteData(), A.Fake<ControllerBase>());

    var myController = GetController();
    myController.ControllerContext = controllerContext;


    myController.Index();

    Assert.Contains("fiddly", sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs.
Maybe it's enough to create a class which will create you fake context instances. Maybe with some methods which allows you to create contexts filled with different data.

```
public class FakeContextFactory
{
     public ControllerContext Create() {/*your mocking code*/}

     public ControllerContext Create(NameValueCollection formVariables) {...}

     ...
}

public void Test()
{
    var context = new FakeContextFactory().Create();
    ...
}
```

In some cases it may be a static factory represented by class with static methods.

If you need a lot of different contexts maybe it's better to use builder pattern.

```
public void Test()
{
    var context = FakeContextBuilder.New()
                      .SetRequestMethod("POST")
                      .Build();
    ...
}
```